# Using PHP to fetch and display contents from a set of pages

Tags: php, html

I have been looking into different answers to similar questions, but this looks a little too specific and complex for me to just work out something from separate solutions. I sometimes use snippets of PHP code but apart from this I am a total PHP newbie.

So I have a group of pages, with random numbers as filenames ("05.html", "12.html" etc.), and I would like to create some sort of index page, using PHP to:

- fetch (I hope I'm using the term correctly) all the pages in the group,
- fetch, inside the pages, the content of a particular div; let's say, the source for an image (div id="pic")
- then display all the fetched contents to have a large list of pictures, along with relevant filenames and links to each page.

So the index page would look something like this:

```
<div class="pages">
  <a href="[PAGENUMBER1].html">
    <img src="[IMG SRC FROM THIS PAGE]">
    <h2>[FILENAME]</h2>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="pages">
  <a href="[PAGENUMBER2].html">
    <img src="[IMG SRC FROM THAT PAGE]">
    <h2>[FILENAME]</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Edit:
@ProEvilz Thank you. A typical page from the "random" pages would look like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="image">
    <img src="img/image.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="caption">
    Here is the caption 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="information">Information</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand what you wish to do.. but this is a strange approach to do it. Please post the contents of one of the random pages so we can see the code structure there.

Comment: Thank you @ProEvilz just added it. I can guess this is quite unorthodox :)

Answer (score -2):

use fopen& fread

```
<?php
 $file=fopen("directory",r);
 echo readfile($file);
echo "<h2>file name</h2>";
?>
```